# Django jinja2 'BoundField' object has no attribute '__call__'

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Why am i getting this error:

```
'BoundField' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

I have function in jinja2.py:

```
class SimpleFilterForm(forms.Form):
    name = fields.CharField(label=_(u'Reči'), required=False)
    parent_category = models.ModelChoiceField(label=_(u'Kategorija'), queryset=Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True), required=False, empty_label='')
    category = MyMultipleChoiceField(label=_(u'Pod kategorije'), queryset=Category.objects.none(), required=False)
    city = models.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=_(u'Gradovi'), queryset=City.objects.all(), required=False)
    ad_type = fields.IntegerField(widget=widgets.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    price__gte = fields.DecimalField(label=_(u'Cena od'), required=False, widget=widgets.TextInput(), localize=True)
    price__lte = fields.DecimalField(label=_(u'Cena do'), required=False, widget=widgets.TextInput(), localize=True)
    currency = models.ModelChoiceField(label=_(u'Valuta'), queryset=Currency.objects.all(), to_field_name='code', required=False, empty_label='')

def cat_filter_form_tag(request, parent_category):
    filter_form = SimpleCatFilterForm(parent_category, request.GET)
    return render(request, 'web/category_ads/filter_form.html', {"filter_form": filter_form})

def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'cat_filter_form_tag': cat_filter_form_tag,
    })

    return env
```

**EDIT:**

template:

```
<div class="sidebox filter-form">
    <h5><span class="fa fa-search"></span> {{ trans('Pretraga') }}</h5>
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ filter_form.name(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="{{ trans('Traži') }}">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Error is on this "name" field.

In django templates it works fine, but with jinja2 it doesn't.

Comment: Sigh. If you're having trouble using this in the template, shouldn't you *post the template*?

Comment: Well, you're trying to call `filter_form.name()`, which is a `BoundField`... not a callable.

Comment: So, how can i call it?

Comment: Why do you think you need to call it? It's not a callable.

Comment: In django templates, i did call it, and it prints "<input type="text"/>", how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know what you did, but you sure didn't call it, that's invalid syntax in django templates. Can you show the template you used with django templates?

Comment: I used widget tweaks template tags, so it was similar.. How can i add class to input in jinja2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call a field, and you don't add classes to it via the template; you do that in the form definition:

```
name = fields.CharField(label=_(u'Reči'), required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

and you just use the attribute in the template:

```
{{ filter_form.name }}
```

Note, there is **no difference** between Jinja and Django templates here.

Comment: Thanks, but i thought i can pass attributes in template, is there solution for that?

Comment: You can pass arguments to functions, yes, but a field is not a function and doesn't accept these attributes at render time.